# Making RewriteRule to mock reddit's or Rails?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For fun I want to make a reddit clone in php. I have mostly java experience but know my way around php, if that matters at all. I also have very limited experince with Rails 3 and I believe how rails deals with URLs is also close to how I want to handle it.

So far in a .htaccess I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This routes every page to index.php where I parse the URI and handle requests with a switch. I know this isn't scalable in the long run but I want to get off the ground.

My next stepis to add a / automaticly at the end of a URL like localhost/r/all so it becomose localhost/r/all/ I want and have tried to make a RewriteRule like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /$1/ [R]
```

This gives a 500 error. I think it is because it gets stuck in an infinite loop of redirect because /$1/ will equal ^/?(.+). So I need something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)Does not end in a forwardlash$ /$1/ [R]
```

How can I do this? I see that the ! charecter can be used to denote a condition it should not match, but I am having trouble getting this to work.

Any Advice is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") //gives /var/www
```

I have /var/www/index.php living, well in /www.
My .htaccess file which I am making these changes to lives in /var.

I have .htaccess in /var because in my httpd.cong I have this:

```
<Directory /var>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I first tried to have it as

```
<Directory /var/www>
```

and putting .htaccess in www but it is never read. I know it is not read becuase I put garbage in it and there is no error. But, if I have garbage in it when it is in /var and the Drectory directive specifies /var I get an error.

Comment: So you want any request URI that does not end in / to be REDIRECTED to the same URI but with / added to the end? Or are you trying to do something else too? I don't understand why you even care about the end slash..

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested):

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on, yada yada yada
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

# We'll want to do the redirect before rewriting anything
# Files obviously don't have a trailing slash, and directories require one - so
# we only need to check if the file exists
# I'm not actually sure if mod_rewrite understands non-capturing groups though
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?((?:.+?)[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

# Do the rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I get the feeling that the problem with your attempt is likely to be the order of the rules, a missing `RewriteCond` on the redirect `RewriteRule` and/or that you didn't put a `L` flag in the redirect `RewriteRule` - but the above regexes make me happier than yours do, because they are a little more specific about what they match.

I'm not actually sure if `mod_rewrite` supports all the regex features I have used above, so if you continue to get an error that might be why - come back here if you do have a problem and I'll look at it more closely.

Comment: The second one does nothing, the first one gives an error: 'RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters'

Comment: @user779608 Try above code, I switched back to your original rule for the actual rewrite.

Comment: It adds the slash which is great but it also adds wwww to it. This: http://localhost/g to 'http://localhost/www/g/'. Could I have set something up incorrectly?

Comment: @user779608 That's being added by something other than the rules above. I've just been testing this and it works exactly as expected on my laptop, is your DocumentRoot directory named `www` by any chance? Which variable are you inspecting to get the URL in PHP?

Comment: In PHP, which variable are you using? You should be using `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` for this...

Comment: ...or I've just realised, do you mean it's adding `www` to the URL you get redirected to? If so that's very odd indeed, are you on shared hosting or a dedicated server?

Comment: I have been using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` It returns the same thing as `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` At least in my case it does.

Comment: @user779608 I have modified the above example to redirect to a full URL instead of just the path. This may cause problems if you need to use HTTPS, but can you try it and see if it fixes the problem and we'll deal with that later...

Comment: The same thing happens. What is really strange is that localhost/www/a/all changes into localhost/www/www/a/all/. It just keeps adding more www(s). Thank's for all the help so far. I upvoted you as this has been very helpful.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I take if from that fact you are using `localhost` that you are working with a development server on your local machine? Did you install it/set it up? How was it installed - via apt-get/yum/<insert repo manager here> or did you build it yourself?

Comment: Yes local machine, it is an Ubuntu 12.04 VM running in VMplayer. I used apt-get to get everything. I added a bit more info in the main post. Like wear the .htaccess file is.

Comment: @user779608 If your .htaccess file is a level above `DocumentRoot`, I'm a little surprised this is working at all. Try moving it to `/var/www/.htaccess` - I'm not 100% sure about that, I'm having a little difficulty working out how this has been functioning, escpecially with respect to the `RewriteBase` directive. If that doesn't fix it, try removing the `RewriteBase` directive.

Comment: I added more to the main post at the end about why .htaccess is in /var and not /var/www. I tried doing what you said any ways but nothing has changed. So now what, another rewrite rule to strip out www? That is a half assed way of solving the problem but I really don't know what is going on.

Comment: @user779608 It's very odd this. No matter what I do I cannot get Apache to process .htaccess files outside `DocumentRoot`. What does the `DocumentRoot` directive in your httpd.conf say? Can you post your entire `httpd.conf` file e.g. on pastebin?

Comment: Actually my httpd.conf only has the directives I put in it. Apache put all of its directives in apache2.conf and included httpd.conf. I found this odd as I have never seen this before. Here is the autogenerated Apache one http://pastebin.com/CFYHvZhG. Here is httpd.conf http://pastebin.com/pYRzT9dv

Comment: I'm not seeing a DocumentRoot directive anywhere in either file - can you add the line `DocumentRoot /var/www` to `httpd.conf`, restart httpd and move .htaccess to `/var/www`? I've never seen that configuration where httpd.conf is not the base configuration file before, this is one reason why I don't use repository packages of Apache/PHP as I like to know exactly how they were built and how they are set up.

Comment: This is really weird. I added the `DocumentRoot /var/www` I moved .htaccess to /www. It still won't read the .htaccess in that directory. I even changed the `<Directory /var>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>` to `<Directory /var/www>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>` still nothing. I then put junk in .htaccess and it didn't even spit out an error.

Comment: FYI I made the LAMP VM by following this: http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/2592-Create-a-Virtual-LAMP-Development-Server I am used to java and windows so I needed a guide like that. I even put ubuntu-desktop on the VM.

Comment: I am, frankly, confused. This may be a little beyond the scope of being able to help without actually having a play around with your machine, which is obviously a non-starter. I am just trying to find some documentation which explains how that distribution of Apache is laid out. I'm guessing from some of the directives in your config files that this is Apache 2.4?

Comment: apache2.conf says to look for docs on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ so I would hope it is apache 2.2

Comment: Surely if you `ps | grep httpd` it will tell you?

Comment: Also, have you definitely restarted Apache after updating the config files?

Comment: I have definitely restarted apache. A few times it wouldn't start because of a mistype...

Comment: Sorry, `ps ax | grep httpd`, I always forget ps doesn't show you all processes by default as the linux system I normally work with doesn't do this.

Comment: Aha! phpinfo() gives me Apache version 2.2.22

Comment: OK. Stepping back from the original problem, if you remove the .htaccess file entirely, can you still load `/index.php`? Or do you have to type `/www/index.php`?

Comment: Without the .htaccess... I don't have to type anything as it defaults to index.php. All of these get me to index.php: localhost, localhost/, localhost/index.php

Comment: I'm ready to just make a new VM and see what happens. Do you know a site with directions to install Apache/php/mysql the "proper way."

Comment: Well I'm afraid I am going to have to resign this one for a little while and go sleep on it (it's nearly 1am here). If you've not got this sorted by tomorrow night I'll spin up a VM and follow the same guide you did to set up the server, and try and repeat the problem myself.

Comment: Of course (I've just realised) a simple work around to this would be handle the redirect in PHP - you could just do this at the top of index.php: `if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -1) != '/') { header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'/'); }`

Comment: I don't know a decent tut off the top of my head cos I never use them, hang on let me see if I can find a sensible looking one. The problem with this is that they will probably apply to old versions and stuff does change between major versions - and both Apache and PHP have recently had new major versions released.

Comment: [This](http://www.web-tech-india.com/articles/php/compiling_php_apache/) is very old but in general looks good and well written, and should get you at least 90% of the way there. TBH a complete reinstall is a little extreme for fixing what I am sure is a simple config error... Right, I am actually going to bed now. I will check back here tomorrow eve to see where you're up to :-)

Comment: I originally was going to do this with redirect through the header() method but I googled around and I kept coming up with responses for "Front Controller." It seems to be the general consensus to do it this way. I would have to worry about query's, but I guess I would just grab all before the (?) tack on the forward slash and then the parameters.

Comment: ...or you could just do `if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -1) != '/') { header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'/'.(!empty($_GET) ? http_build_query($_GET) : '')); }` and handle the query string in PHP. Right, really going this time.

Comment: I may just end up doing this. Thanks for all the help. I need to do some other chores now. I'll mark the answer as right and update my post later saying I am just going to do it in php.